# Restoring a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance with only the C:\ drive

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, migration

I am attempting to migrate a Windows Server 2008 R2 physical server to a proxmox VM with only a backup of the physical servers `C:\` drive.

My approach was to do a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 on proxmox, delete the `C:\` partition, and copy in the backed up `C:\` from the physical server.

As expected this didn't boot.

I then booted into the installation DVD and tried to repair my boot manager (using https://www.ubackup.com/windows-server/how-to-repair-windows-server-2008-r2-using-command-prompt.html). After doing the steps outlined in that blog post the bootmanager would start to load Windows but I would get put into the "Windows Error Recovery" screen where I can either "Start Windows Normally" or "Launch Startup Repair".

Selecting "Launch Startup Repair" tells me:

> "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible",
> Status 0xc000000f.

Selecting Start Windows Normally will result on a BSOD with no useful information (to my eyes, see pic below)

[image: bsod]

The original machine had 4 partitions. `sdb1` - Dell backup partition, `sdb2` boot partition, `sdb3` c:\ (I have a copy of this), `sdb4` extra data partition used for network shares

In the new proxmox VM I have 2 partitions, the boot partition and the main OS partition. Are these mismatched partitions the cause of this problem, if so, how I can direct windows/bootmanager to boot from the 2nd partition instead of the 3rd?

Is there a better way of achieving this goal?

For context: the physical machines HDDs are failing. It contains software that is no longer supported by the vendor, an upgraded version of which would cost $30,000, so starting from fresh is not really an option.

I already tried **Clonezilla** but the images created would not restore correctly. The **Clonezilla** image for `/dev/sdb3` did not contain a valid NTFS filesystem (confirmed by unzipping the image and trying to mount).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty boot partition (with the correct type and filesystem depending on whether Proxmox provides an UEFI environment or only BIOS).

From a Windows install environment, use `bcdboot c:\windows` to install the main bootloader and generate a new bootloader configuration according to the existing system.

If it's a BIOS disk, you'll probably also need `bootrec /nt60 s: /mbr` to install the correct MBR bootcode and the "boot" partition's VBR bootcode.